# how to get an array from a object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I need to get a object from a array using node js I tried the below code but it giving the entire objects. But I need to print only the name for example only sethu I need to print

code:

```
var sethu = [{
    name:'sethu',
    age:24,
    gender:'male'
}]

console.log(sethu)
```

Output:

```
[ { name: 'sethu', age: 24, gender: 'male' } ]
```

Expected output:

```
sethu
```

Comment: `sethu[0].name`

Comment: `const names = sethu.map( item => item.name ); console.log( names )`

Comment: You want to edit your array of objects into an array of strings, or you want that when you print your object in a console, it outputs just the name ??

Comment: Thank you so much @bravemaster this really work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get by 0th index.so you get like this sethu[0]

to access the name property you do the following way.

**sethu[0].name**

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(sethu[0].name)
```

But why do you even define it as an array if you store one element only?

```
var sethu = {
    name:'sethu',
    age:24,
    gender:'male'
}
```

And you can just access it by `sethu.name`.